# How can I prevent keyboard binding from syncing in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code in Mac and Windows. All the sudden VS Code is trying to sync my key binding between the two. Is there a way to stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can disable the syncing of keyboard shortcuts using the command palette:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open command palette.
- Type and select `> Settings Sync: Configure...`

[image]

- Untick the option named `Keyboard shortcuts`

[image]

- Hit the **`OK`** button in the top right and you should be good to go.